# Pentaho data integration to Oracle - long error message

Tags: oracle12c, pentaho-data-integration

I want to connect Pentaho data Integration with my Oraclae database, using the 0jdbc7 connector, but when I try to connect to the Oracle database through Pentaho data integration then I get a very long error message, can you help me what am I doin wrong?

**What did I do:**

Installed Pentaho Business analytics platform, built Pivot4j on top of it. Installed also the data integration tool. All worked well. Also have Oracle database installed, which works great as well – with working I mean within the application everything works accordingly.

**Oracle database configuration**
[image]

But now I want to combine the data integration tool and the Oracle database and now everything goes wrong, I created database in Oracle and wanted to connect to Oracle database through the Pentaho data integration tool, I filled in below settings

**Settup connection**
[image]

o   Connection for local 12c server using SYSTEM account and SID of ORCL.
Connection Name: Oracle12cDB

Connection Type: Oracle

Host Name:

Database Name: 
[image]
(note this link I got through Coursera, where they advised this link)
Port Number:

**The beginning of the error message when I wanted to test:**
[image]

Poort : 1521
Database naam :

Extra information (settings which I used for Oracle setup)
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: You can try with connecting to PDB instead of ROOT container. Based on your setting you can use the following as database URL `(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=pdborcl)))`

Comment: Thanks learningloop for the help! Unfortunately, also with your suggested solution it is still not working. Do you have an idea how I could find what is causing the error? Or are you sure it is the database name which is inccorect?

Comment: Update; if I fill in as database name just "ORCL" then the connection seem to be made. But if I then explore the database, or when I want to make a connection to a certain table which I see in Oracle SQL developer, then it is not seeing the tables which I do see in the SQL developer. So to mee it looks like the database name is incorrect and that I have to make a change there, any suggestions?

Comment: If it is possible can you please check if the listener is up for service PDBORCL ? If the listener is up, you should be able to connect to PDBORCL as service_name. Again, the SID ORCL lands you in ROOT container, not the Pluggable Database.

Comment: Hi Learningloop, I feel we are getting close, which is great! I am not familiar with the listener check, but with some google help. I added in the file tnsnames.ora, the PDBORCL function; copy of ORCL with different servicename: pdborcl. Now within Pentaho I fill in; databasename PDBORCL, Portname 1521, User Name System and my password. Then I still get errors, even when I remove Portnumber or change username to Sys or Anonymous. Do I have to do something extra to solve the issue? Again thanks a lot for your help!!